# difference between folium.features.GeoJson and folium.GeoJson

Tags: leaflet, gis, geospatial, geojson, folium

What is the difference between for the below folium method?
Because when I used both of them, I got the same results.

```
folium.features.GeoJson and folium.GeoJson
```

or

```
folium.features.Choropleth and folium.Choropleth
```